# Decomposition of an $\aleph_1$ set into $\aleph_1$ sets $\aleph_1$

Tags: cardinals, infinity

Can we justify the claim

> Any set of cardinality $\aleph_1$ can be expressed as the disjoint union of $\aleph_1$ sets of cardinality $\aleph_1$

in a simple yet reasonably-correct way?

Comment: As written? Trivially. What you probably meant to write? Please add context like the close votes are suggesting.

Comment: @MarkS. Sorry, I meant disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean a disjoint union. In this cas here's a way to do it :

There is a bijection $f: \aleph_1\times \aleph_1 \to \aleph_1$.

Thus $\aleph_1 = \displaystyle\coprod_{a\in \aleph_1} f(\aleph_1\times\{a\})$.

Of course this partition can be transferred to any set of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Before accepting it lets see if someone else come up with another idea.

Comment: Isn't the question just the same thing as asking to show that there is such a bijection?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo yes somehow...

Comment: @Filburt : if this is what you're asking for, then here is a proof of that result : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2153102/cardinals-arithmetic/2153155#2153155

Comment: Yeah... maybe the answer is simply "no" (the adjective "simple" is pretty subjective though)